# What's the best way to manage an image hierarchy?

Tags: android, ios, uitableview, listview, assets

We're building an app (ios and Android) that lists ~1000 records. This list is displayed in a tableview/listview with an image related to each record displayed in the view. When a record is selected, a detail view opens up and displays multiple images related to that record.
What are some of the best (and simplest) ways to organise these image assets in both platforms and access them?

More info: 
There is also a few lines of text related to each detailed screen. This also needs to be handled.
The images should be packaged with the app as the app will be used offline a lot.

Comment: I don't quite understand the intent of your question. Do you want to package these images for use on both platforms? Where is the images stored? In app or on the cloud?

Comment: The images should be packaged with the apps. I want to know if I should for instance put the images in assets or rather in core data etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS ::
Collection view for display once selecting would probably be the most simple.

1000+ images? That is pretty big and will bloat your ipa for the store, also it locks you into having to add all images. You should really have those on a server and download them when needed, or download all on first load or something.

I'd have thumbnails or something for the tableview then when selected download the related images into a directory on the app bundle. That temp directory can act as your source. Just create a wrapper that reads the directory and creates and ImageObject for each image found (image and text description if available) and compile into a Dictionary with the key being whatever identifies each record.

The wrapper is an important layer when compiling all the images associated with the records because you can swap the implementation if needed as long as you maintain the interface contract of using a Dictionary to organize your data.

The tableview displays all the records and downloads the thumbnails when needed (this is pretty standard). Selecting the record then goes to a collection view that asks the wrapper for the records images/descriptions. The wrapper grabs the either from the system or the server and returns the dictionary. Then the collection view uses the dictionary as the data source displays all the images with the image descriptions

That's how I'd do it based off your vague specs anyhow.

Comment: The specs are vague because I don't know how I want to approach it yet. Your answer gives me enough direction to think things through. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is definitely not recommended to store them in Core Data. Core Data has low performance and can't be cross-platform. I don't see any benefit in storing images into Core Data, and you need to serialize it when displaying.

I recommend that you store your records in a SQLite database. SQLite is a high-performance, cross-platform embedded database that is fully supported by both platforms.

Create a SQLite 3 database and store all the records, but there are two cases for the image:

1. The image is very small, such as the icon of the button, the number of images is less, then you can store them directly in the database.
2. The image is large, the number is large, then it should be stored in the system, only store the name or path of the image into database.

I recommend storing the image in the system, because blob data can't be queried and indexed. It's more troublesome when you need to do something with the image. Reading from the system will be more faster than reading from the database.

Images should be compressed before packaging. If the image is large, creating a corresponding thumbnail will improve UI fluency.

Then you just need to copy the database and images (if not stored in the database) to your apps. When the data changes in the future, you only need to replace the database for your apps.

Comment: This is helpful thanks. Would you recommend something like Firebase for this or is that overkill?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the experience of using Firebase, but if you store data on Firebase, that means the data is on the cloud and the images are also stored on the cloud, and that has nothing to do with the app. That's not your intention to ask this question. In that case, your users must be connected to the Internet to use your app. In addition Firebase is not available in China. Anyway, if you store your data on the cloud, don't forget to add cache to your app to reduce traffic expenses and enhance the user experience.